# Wordpress - Randomize text over a slider [Revolution Slider or similar]

Tags: random, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

I'm using the Revolution Slider plugin for Wordpress.
I have 5 images in my slider and I have 30 short texts. I want to show randomly displaying 1 of these 30 texts every time the slider change image.
Can you suggest me how can I do (also changing plugin)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily added by a short script and a css rule.

**The CSS Part**

```
.forcenoshow { display:none !important}
```

**The JS Part**

```
jQuery('#yoursliderid').bind('.revolution.slide.onafterswap',function() {
  var randomindex = Math.round(Math.random()*30);
  jQuery('.current-sr-slide-visible').find('.tp-caption').each(function(i) {
      if (i!==randomindex) jQuery(this).addClass("forcenoshow");
});
```

This will give all layers within the current slide a "display:none !important" attribute to hide the layer. Only 1 layer from the slide will be visible.

More FAQ and Answer at:  http://themepunch.com/support-center

Comment: I know it's a tad bit old answer, but where does this script go? is it sill valid after almost 2 years?